# Sympy Symbolic Matrix Exponential

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am am trying to find out, if I can somehow find a matrix exponential in kind of closed form for the symbolic matrix:

```
n=3;
a = symbols(['a'+str(1+k) for k in range(n)], real=True);
Ts = symbols('T_s',real=True,positive=True);
A = Matrix([zeros(1,n),eye(1,n),a])
```

however

```
expm(A)
```

seems not to work, "TypeError: cannot create mpf from a1"!
Then I tried to get an estimate using the series expansion, but again:

```
Sum(A**n, (n, 0, 1))
```

gives: "ValueError: Matrix det == 0; not invertible". I guess they try to get the power of the matrix by joran blocks and my structure is not good for that. How can I proceed anyway? `A**2` can be calculated, but the sum over `A**1` and `A**0` not?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `expm` belongs to mpmath library, used by SymPy for numerical calculations. It only works for numerical matrices.

SymPy uses `exp` for [matrix exponentiation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.exp). I recommend using it with `simplify`, as the output of `exp`  for your matrix is more complex than it could be. The simplified result, `simplify(exp(A))`,  is

```
Matrix([
[                                          1,                   0,       0],
[                                          1,                   1,       0],
[(-a2*a3 + (a1*a3 + a2)*(exp(a3) - 1))/a3**2, a2*(exp(a3) - 1)/a3, exp(a3)]])
```

---

If one wishes to compute a partial sum of the power series for exp(A), the way to do it is not

```
Sum(A**n / factorial(n), (n, 0, 5))
```

because the above will attempt to raise A to **symbolic** power n before plugging in specific values. Raising a matrix to symbolic power is   implemented only for invertible A; it's hard to imagine what it should be for non-invertible ones. Instead, use Python's `sum`, giving it a zero matrix as [initial value of the accumulator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sum([A**n / factorial(n) for n in range(6)], zeros(*(A.shape)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I still wonder, why the sum didn't work, but exp exactly does the job! Nice! I grow to love sympy!

Comment: Very glad for the 2 explanations! Much to learn here! Much appreciated!